# Input values were not transmitted to the PostMapping controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-validator, spring-validation

**create.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<a th:href="@{/admin/}">Admin</a>
<br>
<br>


<br>

<h1>Add core phrases to the database</h1>
<br>

<br>
<form method="POST" th:object="${corePhrasesCreateForm}">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Quotation cluster (" "):</td>
            <td><input
                    type="number"
                    id="quotation-cluster"
                    name="quotation-cluster"
                    th:value="${quotationCluster}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('quotationCluster')}" th:errors="*{quotationCluster}">quotationCluster</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quotation Exclamation cluster ("!")</td>
            <td><input

                    type="number"
                    id="quotation-exclamation-cluster"
                    name="quotation-exclamation-cluster"
                    th:value="${quotationExclamationCluster}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('quotationExclamationCluster')}" th:errors="*{quotationExclamationCluster}">quotationExclamationCluster</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phrases</td>
            <td><textarea rows="5" cols="60" name="value" placeholder="Key phrases" th:text="${value}"></textarea></td>
            <td class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('value')}" th:errors="*{value}">value</td>
        </tr>
    </table>    


    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Validator**

```
import com.example.marketing3.semantics.semanticsClusters.repositories.ClusterRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class CorePhraseFormValidator implements Validator {
    private final ClusterRepository clusterRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        System.out.println();

}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/semantics/phrases/core")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CorePhraseController {

    @GetMapping({"/create", "/create/"})
    public String createGet(CorePhrasesCreateForm corePhrasesCreateForm) {

        return "semantics/phrases/core/create";
    }

    @PostMapping({"/create", "/create/"})
    public String createPost(@Valid CorePhrasesCreateForm corePhrasesCreateForm,
                             BindingResult bindingResult,
                             RedirectAttributes atts) {

        corePhraseFormValidator.validate(corePhrasesCreateForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "semantics/phrases/core/create";
        }

        atts.addAttribute("message", "Core phrases created");

        String result = "";

        return "redirect:/general/message";
    }

}
```

The form has been rendered.
I entered

Quotation cluster (" "): 1
Quotation Exclamation cluster ("!"): 2

And some text for phrases.

Like this:

[image]

**The problem:**

To createPost quotationCluster and quotationExclamationCluster came as zeroes.

[image]

But I entered 1 and 2 respectively.

What have I done wrongly, and how can I correct the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<input type="number" id="quotation-cluster"
       name="quotation-cluster" th:value="${quotationCluster}"/>
```

To:

```
<input type="number" id="quotation-cluster" th:field="*{questionCluster}"
       name="quotationCluster" th:value="${quotationCluster}"/>
```

the name and th:field should be same as the declared attribute in your java class CorePhraseForm. Repeat this for the the next input (Textarea).